# Most performant way to convert a recursive hierarchy in MySQL to Core Data

Tags: mysql, ios, database, algorithm

**EDIT** right now I'm writing a two-pass algorithm that first creates all the parents and then sets all the children (as of Aug 7 at 9:30pm)

I want to know if I'm better off using SQLite than Core Data for storing and querying a recursive hierarchy, simply to avoid time it takes to convert the sql rows to a Core Data store.

Here's a way I could convert the sql rows into a Core Data store:
I have a hierarchy of categories in MySQL. Each row has a `categoryId`, `name`, and `parentId`, where the `parentId` is the `categoryId` of the category that contains it. I want to convert this table to Core Data. I could iterate through the array of rows to produce an `NSDictionary` in which each entry has a key that is a parent category name and a value that is an array of child names. Then I could use a recursive function to insert objects into Core Data.

The time complexity of each operation in this process is:

- `O(n^2)` to sort the MySQL entries by `parentId`
- `O(n)` to parse the mysql rows `O(n)` to find the children for each parent (given the rows are ordered by parentId)
- `O(n^2)` to get each category name by id
- Something like `O(n)` to recursively convert the `NSDictionary` into `Core Data` objects, given that the number of children is always < 10.

Comment: I'm hatin' on core data at the moment.  Its sure been a pain for us on our big project.

Answer (score 0):

> "if I'm better off using SQLite **than** Core Data"

Core data uses SQLite. Perhaps I'm not getting the Question.

Are you suggesting using a) Core Data with SQLite; versus, b) Core Data simply to do a NSFetchPredicate (or what-have-you) on data that is stored in MySQL. ... Then the question becomes MySQL vs SQLite

One thing to note: You can compare Core Data using SQLite versus Binary -- with the bonus of no code change.

Comment: The decision is to whether interact with SQLite or the standard wrapper around it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, yes, I can easily convert a recursive hierarchy in MySql to Core Data. Here's the simple two-pass algorithm. First insert all the parents in the db. Then add add each child to its parent.

```
+ (void)populateCategories {
    [[ROAPIManager sharedInstance] request:GET
                                  endpoint:@"test_categories"
                                parameters:nil
                                   success:^(NSArray *data) {
                                       if ([data  count] > 0) {
                                           [self insertParentCategoriesIntoCoreDataFromArray:data];
                                           [self insertChildCategoriesIntoCoreDataFromArray:data];
                                       }
                                   }
                                     error:^(ROAPIError *error) {
                                         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:error.message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LocalizedOK", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                         [alert show];
                                     }
                                    failed:^{
                                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:NSLocalizedString(@"ErrorDuringSetup", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LocalizedOK", nil) otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                        [alert show];
                                    }];
}

+ (void)insertParentCategoriesIntoCoreDataFromArray:(NSArray *)array {
    ROAppDelegate *delegate = (ROAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *categoryEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ROCategory" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        ROCategory *category = [[ROCategory alloc] initWithEntity:categoryEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        NSArray *mySQLRow = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *name = [mySQLRow objectAtIndex:1];
        [category setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
    }
}

+ (void)insertChildCategoriesIntoCoreDataFromArray:(NSArray *)array {
    ROAppDelegate *delegate = (ROAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *categoryEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ROCategory" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        NSArray *mySQLRow = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        // can't add the topmost category as a child
        if (![[mySQLRow objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]]) {
            NSString *name = [mySQLRow objectAtIndex:1];

            // fetch the child by name
            NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            [request setEntity:categoryEntity];
            request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name LIKE[c] \'%@\'", name]];

            NSError *error;
            NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
            if (!mutableFetchResults) {
                // major alert
            }

            if ([mutableFetchResults count] > 0) {
                ROCategory *childEntity = [mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
                [childEntity setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
                NSNumber *parentId = [mySQLRow objectAtIndex:2];
                ROCategory *parentEntity = [self parentEntityForId:parentId inArray:array];
                if (parentEntity) {
                    NSMutableOrderedSet *children = [parentEntity mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"children"];
                    [children addObject:childEntity];
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@" ERROR there were no results returned");
            }
        }
    }
}
```